# Java Webapp: catch 22 regarding dev/prod builds for a .war

Tags: java, web-config, web-applications

There's something I just don't get regarding config files and dev or prod environments.

If you have a *.war* and want to use the same *.war* in dev and prod (because the point of the dev environment being, well, to test that the *.war* is working fine, hence you don't want to test that *.war* and then deploy **another** *.war* right!?), then where do you put the config file telling if your environment is dev or prod?

Say locally I've got user */Users/Alex* (on OS X) testing the *.war* and then, if everything looks fine, I want to deploy on a Linux machine in a */home/tomcat/* repertory.

Where and how do I access the config file telling if it's a dev or a prod environment?

Don't tell me people are building two different *.war* for dev and prod builds right!?  That would kinda completely defeat the purpose...

Comment: What's Catch-22? I've read the wiki article but I didn't get it

Comment: @OscarRyz: This Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic) ?    Basically, it's often used in english.  Here, I was explaining that the whole point of the "test" environment was to test the *.war* but that to be able to do test, I need to modify the *.war*, which makes it that it defeats the very purpose of testing in the first place, because I'm not testing the *.war* I plan to put in prod.  So it's a kind of a catch-22, in a way :)   It's a cool term with a cool history (and I'm not a native english speaker).

Comment: @OscarRyz: An example of a Catch-22 (I think) would be the following: you'd like to open a safe.  But for this you need to find the safe's key.  But you know that the safe's key is inside the safe (and hence you cannot open the safe).  That's a Catch-22 as far as I can tell :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have to rebuild the WAR to move from one environment to another.

You can externalize configuration to a database, of course, but that won't help much with Spring.

Another thought is to have a configuration file set for each environment, with the name embedded in the names (e.g., "config-devl.xml", "config-test.xml", "config-prod.xml").  Have an environment variable set for each environment that matches the postfix value.  Have your app read the config files with the postfix value set by the environment variable on startup.

Comment: I haven't used Spring yet but why isn't externalization to a DB compatible with Spring? (inquiring mind wants to know : )

Comment: It uses XML or annotations for configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem which has several solutions.

The one which most people (in my experience) seem to use is to have a build script which generates the .war file. The build script can be Ant or Maven, it doesn't really matter - but Ant will require a little bit more work to set up.

You then have a master properties file (or something like that) which contains all your properties for database access etc. in all your different environments. Then, when you run your build script it simply sets the properties in the right places, and you have what is essentially the same .war file - just configured for different environments.

Maven does this pretty much "out of the box" - have a look at [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: +1 this is what we do as well. we use Ant and it's not too difficult to set up :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way around it is to build environment specific config outside of your .war.  That way you can deploy the same war with separate configuration in different environments.

Getting to the config can be done in a number of ways:

- Place config in the $CATALINA_HOME/lib or similar where it will be loaded in the application server classpath.
- Place it in the home directory of the user that executes the application and point your app to that location.
- Do some JNDI magic (generally this is too difficult for me so I stay clear of it).

To have more certainty about your deploy you can use a deploy tool like [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org).  Often devs do some pre-deployment sanity checking on prod configuration (obviously it hasn't been tested yet) to make sure the app will run.